# Manga about a girl who travels back to the time of her grandparents and finds her grandpa is a psycho who kills girls

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

A girl travels back in time and finds that her grandpa is a psycho and witnesses him murder another girl in his garden.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was in a full color

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*Garden of the Dead Flowers*](https://www.webtoons.com/id/thriller/dead-flowers/list?title_no=2372&page=1).

> When Mila woke up, she suddenly returns to the past in Batavia during
> the Dutch colonial period. She accidentally saw her grandfather at a
> young age, kill a girl! Her grandfather, who she thought was nice,
> actually killed girls in his garden and planted them into flowers.
>
> [image]